# BigQuery : best use of UNNEST Arrays

Tags: sql, database, select, google-bigquery, unnest

I really need some help, I have a big file JSON that I ingested into BigQuery, I want to write a query that uses UNNEST twice, namely I have this  like :

```
{
  "categories": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "C0",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "Property_1",
        "value": {
          "type": "String",
          "value": "11111"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Property_2",
        "value": {
          "type": "String",
          "value": "22222"
        }
      }
    ]}
]}
```

And I want to do a query that give's me something like this result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Category_ID  |  Name_ID   |   Property_1      |    Property_2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1       |   C0       |        11111      |        22222  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I already made something like but it's not working :

```
SELECT 
   c.id as Category_ID,
   c.name as Name_ID,
   p.value.value as p.name
From `DataBase-xxxxxx` CROSS JOIN
UNNEST(categories) AS c, 
UNNEST(c.properties) AS p;
```

Thank you more

Comment: double check and fix your json sample in question - as it is right now  - it is wrong!

Comment: You might forget `]` at the end.

Comment: Yess I Thaaank you, like when I took a piece of JSON code I forgot, but it's not the problem